# To pull out records from an access database multiple time according to the time frame

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an access database that has some tickets related data. They all have 2 columns - Opening Date and Closing date with a ticket number as primary key!
I want to pull out how many records we open by the end of Jan, how many were open by the end of feb, etc.
So, if a ticket with Ticket ID TKT1, "Opening Date" = Jan 12 and "Closing Date" = March 5 then 
if I pull out count of tickets, this TKT1 should be counted for Jan end's and Feb end's tickets as well. 
Is there a query with which we could implement this?

Comment: So you have 12 columns for each ticket number?

Comment: I can add if I want to. Adding a flag for every month the ticket is open and then pull records based on that?

Comment: No what I meant was do you want a column for every month of the year for each ticket in the Query ?

Comment: Yes! I need a column for every month of the year -  that would show the count of open tickets by the end of that month.

Comment: Number of open Tickets at the end of each month   
App Names Jan-15 Feb-15 Mar-15,
App A                4    0           2,
App B                  6    5          1,
App C                 8    3          0.
This is the format in which I want the data. TKT1 might be opened in Jan and its still open. It is from APP B. So it accounts for the counts 6,5, and 1 in the above Table. Because it was open by the end of those months